# StepFunctions - Using States.Format with SNS publish

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to run a StepFunction Step using the [SNS integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sns.html) with the following step definition:

```
"HandleError": {
    Type: 'Task',
    Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::sns:publish',
    Parameters: {
        TopicArn: `arn:aws:sns:region:accountid:topic`,
        "Message.$": "States.Format('Message: {}', $.message)",
    }
}
```

`message` is defined as an input to the step. According to the examples in the [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) documentation and integration documentation, this should be doable. However, it's throwing an error, complaining:

`The value for the field 'Message.$' must be a valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call (at /States/HandleError/Parameters)`

Did I do something wrong? Can the SNS integration for Step Function use an intrinsic function for the Message body?

Comment: What shape does your input JSON have?

Comment: Is it complaining at execution or deployment time? 
Have you tried passing the whole state input instead of selecting the message (just to try and see whether it's working or not)?
Just to be sure it's not depending on JSON syntax, change those backticks to "normal" quotes. 
Anyway, try to explore what's going on by using the Data flow simulator https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/simulator

Comment: @fedonev te the input has the shape `{ message: "Error message" }`

Comment: The syntax looks OK.  The Parameters field [supports intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions-states).  Does `"Message.$": "$.message"` cause an error?

Comment: Oh yea it works now, it turns out I have typo. I did not correctly escape the template string. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue and it turned out that States.Format() does not like multiline strings.
I was rendering some multiline query strings and I solved this by replacing "\n" with " " before passing the string to States.Format()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"HandleError": {
    Type: 'Task',
    Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::sns:publish',
    Parameters: {
        TopicArn: `arn:aws:sns:region:accountid:topic`,
       "Message.$": JsonPath.stringAt(
                        "States.Format('Message: {}', $.message)",
                    ),
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).